# C# и Entity Framework. Вызов метода ToList() у всех свойств типа DbSet<T> в DbContext

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, рефлексия, полиморфизм

Имеется база данных деталей и иерархия наследования классов. Хочу запихнуть в один лист главного типа Detail все объекты типов-наследников, взяв данные из всех имеющихся таблиц БД и вывести на экран. Однако, почти не знаком с рефлексией и совершенно не представляю, как это сделать.
Ниже я предоставлю ***абстрактный*** (неправильный) код, который передаст суть того, что я хочу сделать. Спасибо.

```
List<Detail> allDetails = new List<Detail>();
    public void ShowData()
    {
        using(var db = new DetailsDbContext())
        {
            // Абстрактный код

            Type dbContType = typeof(DetailsDbContext);
            var props = dbContType.GetProperties();
            foreach(var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.Name.EndsWith('s'))
                {
                    foreach(var det in prop.ToList())
                    {
                        allDetails.Add(det);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Конец абстрактного кода

            //Вывод на экран
        }
```

Класс DetailsDbContext:

```
public class DetailsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AlternateResistor> AlternateResistors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnalogMicrocircuit> AnalogMicrocircuits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CeramicCapacitor> CeramicCapacitors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ComputerSystem> ComputerSystems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConstantResistor> ConstantResistor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ElectrolyticCapacitor> ElectrolyticCapacitors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HighFreqConnector> HighFreqConnector { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HighFreqDiode> HighFreqDiodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inductance> Inductances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LightDiode> LightDiodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogicMicrocircuit> LogicMicrocircuits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LowFreqConnector> LowFreqConnectors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MembraneCapacitor> MembraneCapacitors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RectifyingDiode> RectifyingDiodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Relay> Relays { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Switcher> Switchers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Thyristor> Thyristors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transistor> Transistors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ZenerDiode> ZenerDiodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt) 
        => opt.UseSqlite("Data Source= Detailsdata.db");

    
}
```

Comment: `var propValue = prop.GetValue(db)` вернет вам  объект, сохраненный в свойстве

Comment: @aepot а как потом итерироваться по этому объекту? Он ведь возвращает EntityType. Имея одну таблицу я бы прописал db.AlternateResistors.ToList(), а мне нужно в цикле обработать все свойства (таблицы) Однако, у object`а нет метода разширения ToList<>

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что List<T> - обобщенный тип, а обобщенные типы задаются на этапе компилации. Рефлексия тоже поддерживает обобщения во время выполнения, DbSet реализует IEnumerable и IQueryable, можно кастануть этот object в более подходящий интерфейс.

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит вызывать `ToList` - это приведёт к загрузке всех данных в память. У вас наверняка маленькая БД, но в реальном проекте это может оказаться фатальным. Во-вторых, вы же в конечном итоге используете лишь свойства родительского типа `Detail`. Значит, из БД нужно грузить лишь данные из некоторых колонок, которые относятся именно к Detail, а не все колонки. Что опять-таки слишком расточительно.